# How do I resize a base64 image?

Tags: php, database, image, server, base64

I am developing a web app with Construct 2 and now I am creating the user profile, where the user uploads an image. This image is encoded into base64 and sent via AJAX (POST) to my web server, where it is stored as a base64 string in a database. The problem is, I often get this error "The requested URL's length exceeds the capacitylimit for this server." when I try to upload images over 1MB. I really do not care at all about resolution, as the profile image is displayed as a 200x200 image.

So here comes my question: How do I resize a base64 image to then send it to my database? Note that it is impossible to resize the image in Construct 2: Once the user picks the image, it is inmediately encoded into base64, before I can even resize it.

Comment: Why not use the body of the request to keep the image? It wouldn't even have to be in Base64.

Comment: Why are you sending the base64 string as part of the URL instead of as a post variable?